# App rejected due to crash

Tags: ios, crash

Hi my app rejected due to crash, but i can't reproduce the crash from my side. Apples send following crash log:

```
    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39146a50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39146849 mach_msg + 37
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2df99625 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 153
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2df97d8b __CFRunLoopRun + 859
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2df02765 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2df02547 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
6   GraphicsServices                0x32e396cf GSEventRunModal + 135
7   UIKit                           0x3086188d UIApplicationMain + 1133
8   tiein                           0x000df55f 0x7c000 + 406879
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x390a2ab5 start + 1

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39146804 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x39095051 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 229
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3908f2df _dispatch_mgr_thread + 35

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39146a50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39146849 mach_msg + 37
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2df99625 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 153
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2df97d45 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2df02765 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2df02547 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
6   Foundation                      0x2e8f5493 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 251
7   Foundation                      0x2e946255 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 77
8   tiein                           0x00154241 0x7c000 + 885313
9   Foundation                      0x2e9b7a0b __NSThread__main__ + 1059
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391c0957 _pthread_body + 139
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391c08c7 _pthread_start + 99
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391beae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39159c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391bec1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391bead8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39159c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391bec1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391bead8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39146a50 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39146849 mach_msg + 37
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2df99625 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 153
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2df97d45 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2df02765 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2df02547 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
6   Foundation                      0x2e94223d +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 317
7   Foundation                      0x2e9b7a0b __NSThread__main__ + 1059
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391c0957 _pthread_body + 139
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391c08c7 _pthread_start + 99
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391beae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39159434 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2df9d51f __CFSocketManager + 483
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391c0957 _pthread_body + 139
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391c08c7 _pthread_start + 99
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391beae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x391591f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391c17b3 pthread_kill + 55
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39109ff5 abort + 73
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3855898b abort_message + 71
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x385716e3 default_terminate_handler() + 251
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38ba4f7b _objc_terminate() + 191
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3856f1b1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 77
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3856ea05 __cxa_throw + 113
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38ba4db7 objc_exception_throw + 247
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2df0a1bb -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 815
10  tiein                           0x000f7901 0x7c000 + 506113
11  tiein                           0x000eb7b3 0x7c000 + 456627
12  tiein                           0x00102c59 0x7c000 + 552025
13  Foundation                      0x2e9b7a0b __NSThread__main__ + 1059
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391c0957 _pthread_body + 139
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391c08c7 _pthread_start + 99
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391beae4 thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39159c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391bec1f _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x391bead8 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00002060
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x02559000      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x02557f54
    r8: 0x14553fd0    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x146d7a80     r11: 0x146ebbb0
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x02557f48      lr: 0x391c17b7      pc: 0x391591f0
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

App crashes in login page, during login I am sending  device token to server. If the token is nil it will crash(it might be a problem). But is any case arrives not getting the device token?

Comment: You need to symbolicate this log. That should tell you more.

Comment: It sounds like you already know what the problem is. It crashes on `-[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]` when you attempt to insert a nil token.

Comment: If you do not have internet connection, you will not receive device token. Test the application with Air plane mode. And probably you are trying to set this nil token to dictionary

Comment: Any other case absence of device token, if there is no net i am not calling the webservice

Comment: @Apurv that isn't true. " If your application has previously registered, calling registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: results in the operating system passing the device token to the delegate immediately without incurring additional overhead.

It implies that if your application is already registered for push notifications, calling the registerForRemoteNotificationTypes doesn't access the APNS server." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432793/device-token-received-even-after-iphone-is-not-connected-to-internet

Comment: Why not just properly handle the error of the token being nil?

Comment: I have handled nill, whether apple restricts there device token of their device.