# App rejected due to crash on app store

Tags: xcode, crash-reports, itunes-app

I had developed an app and uploaded it on app store. The app got rejected due to crash. But my problem is that I cannot detect this crash while running app on device for testing. App is working properly on the device.

The app is been created in unity and then I had exported it to xCode.

So I want to ask that how can I get to know about where it is getting crashed. Also how can I traverse the crash log.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, app was getting crashed on devices with 64 bit architecture. as older version of unity don't support 64 bit architecture. Unity 4.6.2 onwards support 64 bit architecture. Thus rebuild the ios app and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did they tell you about:

– Where crash happened? (At launch, On logging in, or in specific screen)

– Did they send you any images?

– Which devices and iOS they were testing

– They will surely send you crash log, please post it.

You said you cannot replicated the crash, but did you tried with simulator or real devices?

Since you are missing many information, I cannot give you a certain answer. My advice for you is to

1) Updating your question

2) Read my [post](http://cungcode.com/app-rejected-due-to-crash-now-what/) about how to do when your app got rejected, or my [post](http://cungcode.com/how-to-symbolicate-crash-log-ios/) about how to symbolicate crash log

3) You can also follow the topics in stackoverflow: [Iphone App was Rejected Due to We found your app crashed on launch so we were unable to review it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818879/iphone-app-was-rejected-due-to-we-found-your-app-crashed-on-launch-so-we-were-un) and [App rejected due to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284996/app-rejected-due-to-crash). They are very helpful